# How can I get reliable data updates with objects in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling with data updates in D3.js. While everything works as expected when the data consists of simple arrays like `var data = [1,2,3,4,5]`, I get unreliable updates if I try it with arrays of objects like `var data = [{i:1,d:"a"}, {i:1,d:"a"}]`. Here is an example that should run out of the box in your browser (if you store and call it as html page):

```js
function randomLetters() {
  // see https://devdocs.io/d3~6/d3-array#shuffle
  // https://devdocs.io/d3~6/d3-array#sort
  var array = d3
    .shuffle([
      { d: "1", t: "h" },
      { d: "2", t: "g" },
      { d: "3", t: "f" },
      { d: "4", t: "e" },
      { d: "5", t: "d" },
      { d: "6", t: "c" },
      { d: "7", t: "b" },
      { d: "8", t: "a" },
    ])
    .slice(0, 4)
    .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.t, b.t));
  var result = array.slice(0); // copy
  return result;
}
function update() {
  var llist = d3.select("#list");
  data = randomLetters();
  console.log("New data:");
  console.log(data);
  llist
    .selectAll("li")
    // Without the key function, the data is not properly sorted
    .data(data, function (d) {
      d ? d.d : this.id;
    })
    .join(
      (enter) => {
        enter.each((d) => console.log("enter: ", d));
        enter
          .append("li")
          .text((d) => d.d)
          .attr("id", (d) => d.d);
      },
      (update) => {
        update.each((d) => console.log("update: ", d));
      },
      (exit) => {
        exit.each((d) => console.log("exit: ", d));
        exit.remove();
      }
    );
}
data = randomLetters();
setInterval(() => update(), 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you look at the javascript console output in almost all cases the latest data will not be equal to the displayed data. If you look at the updates, it seems elements that have existed in an update will be removed and re-inserted instead of properly updated. Also the first shown element is not updated at all. Looking at the source of `d3.selection_data()` method, I could not see what would the possible reason for such behavior. As stated above, using a simple array seems to be fine.

Given the data above: **how do I get correct updates?**

Comment: I partially rolled your edit back to the previous version because you edited the solution from your self-answer into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question contains a bug in the `.data()`'s key function: no value is returned. While I really don't know how this works at all, it will work correct if instead this key function is used:

```
...
.data(data, function (d) {
  return d ? d.d : this.id;
})
...
```

So just the `return` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a correct use of the D3 enter / exit pattern:

```js
function randomLetters() {
  return d3.shuffle([
    { d: "1", t: "h" },
    { d: "2", t: "g" },
    { d: "3", t: "f" },
    { d: "4", t: "e" },
    { d: "5", t: "d" },
    { d: "6", t: "c" },
    { d: "7", t: "b" },
    { d: "8", t: "a" },
  ])
  .slice(0, 4)
  .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.t, b.t));
}

function update() {
  const llist = d3.select("#list");
  const data = randomLetters();
  const entries = llist.selectAll("li")
    .data(data, d => d.d);
          
  const newEntries = entries.enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(d => d.t);

  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
  newEntries.merge(entries)
    .style('color', (d, i) => colors[i]);

  entries.exit().remove();
}

setInterval(() => update(), 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The downvote was probably caused by your comment  about the correct use of the enter/exit pattern. The `.join()` that I used in the example was introduced with v6 of D3 I believe (see [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join)). I gave you a upvote for your example which I could compare to my code to finally see my mistake - the provided key function in my example which was missing a return. :-(